# where is function filter counter function?

Tags: filter

```
catalog/layer/filter.phtml

<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
     <?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>
```

Where is getCount function? and how to modify it? I need to get count without filter affection.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method.
`getCount` is a magic getter.
It translates to `$_item->getData('count')`.

The value returned by `getCount` is previously set to the item by calling `$item->setCount($count)`.

The actual item creation happens in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract::_createItem`.  This `_createItem` method is called by `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract::_initItems` that uses the value returned by the `_getItemsData` method in all the classes that can be filter items.
These classes depend on the filter type and are:

- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Attribute`
- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Category`
- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Decimal`
- `Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price`

Look in these methods for something like this `'count' => ....`. That's where `count` comes from.

Comment: I need to hide filter option if there isn't any product. I can't use $_item->getCount() because it return product count with filter affection.